# Trim() input value of any TextField in a Form by default in flutter app

Tags: forms, flutter, input, dart, trim

I have different form fields and I want to trim each value of the form field by default before the `validator` method gets fired.

The reason I want to achieve this is because if I run a `regex` on an Input value when the `validator` method gets fired, the regex will return false on `input_text.hasMatch` because of a useless space character at the end of the input value.

For example. The code below on `alphaNumericText.hasMatch(val)` will return false because of a useless extra space character(s) at the end of the input value.

```dart
final alphaNumericText = RegExp(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$');

TextFormField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Enter your nickname',
                  ),
                  validator: (val) {
                    if (val.isEmpty == true) {
                      return 'Nickname is required!';
                    }
                    if (alphaNumericText.hasMatch(val) == false) {
                      return 'Use alphanumeric characters only in nickname.';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (val) => this.nickname = val,
                ),
```

**Note** I do not want to achieve this by modifying the `alphaNumericText RegExp` to entertain extra spaces at the end of input value. I do not want to achieve this in this way.

What I want is every value in all TextFields in a form to be **validated** by default before the `validator` method is called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just add

```
inputFormatters: [WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]'))],
```

as property to TextInputField
and user will not even able to type space or any other chars except whitelisted
and you can remove also additional checks from validator

full example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: TextFormField(
              inputFormatters: [WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]'))],
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Enter your nickname',
              ),
              validator: (val) {
                if (val.isEmpty == true) {
                  return 'Nickname is required!';
                }
                return null;
              },
              onSaved: (val) {},
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: WhitelistingTextInputFormatter is deprecated, use FilteringTextInputFormatter instead.

Comment: Trim() means removing spaces at the end, not disallowing them altogether.

Answer (score 4):

As @Darish suggested, here is the sample code for it.

A caveat though, need to select at the end of `text` if trimmed. This will only work if spaces in between are disallowed.

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final alphaNumericText = RegExp(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$');
  final textController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    textController?.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: TextFormField(
          controller: textController,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          decoration: new InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Enter your nickname',
          ),
          onChanged: (val) {
            final trimVal = val.trim();
            if (val != trimVal)
              setState(() {
                textController.text = trimVal;
                textController.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: trimVal.length));
              });
          },
          validator: (val) {
            if (val.isEmpty == true) {
              return 'Nickname is required!';
            }
            if (alphaNumericText.hasMatch(val) == false) {
              return 'Use alphanumeric characters only in nickname.';
            }
            return null;
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Trim the text value on [onChanged](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/onChanged.html) callback and assign it back to the controller.

Answer (score -1):

I used following logic inside validation function. I created custom stateless widget by wrapping `TextFormField`. Because I wanted to use same style `TextFormField` inside my app. `validator` is the function I passed to that stateless widget.

```
  validator: (value) {
    if(validator != null){
      if(obscureText){
        return validator(value);
      }else{
        return validator(value.trim());
      }
    }
    return null;
  },
```

You can use same logic in `onFieldSubmitted` and `onSaved`. Trimming is ignored when set `obscureText` to `true`. Because we don't want passwords to trim.